# How to bind WP7 user control element to a property of the user control

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

I've built a user control called UserControl1.  Inside the control I havea textblock.  In the UserControl1 class, I've created a property called DisplayText.  How can I bind the textblock's text value to the DisplayText property of the user control?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a UserControl as follows:

```
<UserControl class="MyUserControl">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And MyUserControl defines a `DisplayText` dependency property. Within the constructor set the `DataContext` of `LayoutRoot` to the user control:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
  LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

You can now bind the `TextBlock` as follows:

```
<UserControl class="MyUserControl">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayText}/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This works because the `DataContext` of the grid is inherited by your `TextBlock`. This then becomes the source of the binding.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  The textblock does not appear to update the text value when the displaytext property changes.